# How to change the underlining color of the Native Base Tab

Tags: react-native, vue-native

I am trying desperately to change the color used to underline the selected tab in the NativeBase element Tab https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref . So fare I have been able to change the text color of the selected element to red but there seems to be no way of doing it for the underlings blue bar.

here is The Vue native template which can use every react native element.

```
<template>
<nb-container :style="{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}">
    <header v-bind:title="title" ></header>
    <nb-tabs>
      <nb-tab :heading="heading1" :textStyle="textStyle" :activeTextStyle="activeTextStyle" :tabStyle="tabStyle" :activeTabStyle="activeTabStyle">
            <actualitesVue  v-bind:navigation= "navigation" > </actualitesVue>
        </nb-tab>
        <nb-tab heading="Dossiers" :textStyle="textStyle" :activeTextStyle="activeTextStyle" :tabStyle="tabStyle" :activeTabStyle="activeTabStyle">
            <dossiersVue  v-bind:navigation= "navigation" > </dossiersVue>
        </nb-tab>
    </nb-tabs>
</nb-container>
```

here is the  prop

```
data: function () {
        return {
          heading1: "Actualités",
          title : "INFOS",
          tabStyle : {backgroundColor: "white"},
          activeTabStyle : {backgroundColor: "white"},
          textStyle : {color: "rgba(189,40,26,0.6)"},
          activeTextStyle : {color : "rgba(189,40,26,1)", fontSize: 20 },
        }
    },
```

And the result is close to this. My point is about the blue line:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can change :

```
<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
....
</Tabs>
```